# Fuzzy Lookup add-in is pasting the results in a semi-random location

Tags: microsoft-excel

"Fuzzy Lookup Add-In for Excel", for reference, is available [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15011).

I get a bunch of "headers" that keep changing - both in name (a little bit) and in location. So off to fuzzy matching land to figure out where things are this time, and what they're called. The first time I run a fuzzy match, it works! I get the details as shown in the picture. (The table indicated by `Headers` is the source, and the one indicated by `Matching` contains the results.)

When I run it again, however, the results end up in the lower right, as shown in the picture. Why is that? How can I prevent this from happening and get the data to consistently end up where I want it?

(And yes, I can see that "Discounts" shouldn't match with "Gross Amt Minus Discounts" a second time - it should be blank. That's fixable just by fiddling with the settings.)

[image: Error picture]

Comment: When you say "when I run it again however", can you describe the exact steps you take?

Comment: Sure. I hit "Go" (bottom right corner), and I get the Headers and Similarity added to my table. Nice. I hit "Go" again - and that's when the extra/misplaced data is added. I changed none of the settings, and nothing in either table.

Comment: If you are "hitting go" that means there is a dialog. What are the fields in the dialog? Do you select input / output ranges?

Comment: It looks like they were cut out of the picture - It's at the very bottom of the fuzzy lookup dialog box on the right. The fuzzy lookup box remains open with the same settings after you use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't directly script the `Fuzzy Lookup` add-in, but I've managed to work-around most of the bugs and issues with it.

The following code will "lock" the output location to the specified table, irrespective of the position of the active cell using the
 `Workbook_SheetChange` and `Workbook_SheetSelectionChange` events:

```
'============================================================================================
' Module     : ThisWorkbook
' Version    : 1.0
' Part       : 1 of 1
' References : N/A
' Source     : https://superuser.com/a/1283003/763880
'============================================================================================
Option Explicit

Private Const s_FuzzyLookupResultsTable As String = "MatchingTable"
Private Const RESTORE_SELECTION As Boolean = True

Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange _
            ( _
                       ByVal TheWorksheet As Object, _
                       ByVal Target As Range _
            )
        Dim Ä As Excel.Application: Set Ä = Excel.Application
        Dim ƒ As Excel.WorksheetFunction: Set ƒ = Excel.WorksheetFunction

  Const l_FuzzyLookup_AddIn_Undo_Sheet As String = "FuzzyLookup_AddIn_Undo_Sheet"
  Const s_InCell_Error_Message As String = "SAVE, CLOSE & REOPEN if pressing GO again doesn't fix it"

  Static swkstActiveFuzzyLookupSheet As Worksheet
  Static sstrOriginalSelection As String

  Select Case True
    Case TheWorksheet.Name <> l_FuzzyLookup_AddIn_Undo_Sheet And swkstActiveFuzzyLookupSheet Is Nothing:
      Exit Sub
    Case TheWorksheet.Name = l_FuzzyLookup_AddIn_Undo_Sheet And swkstActiveFuzzyLookupSheet Is Nothing:
      'TODO If missing table
      Set swkstActiveFuzzyLookupSheet = ActiveSheet
      sstrOriginalSelection = Selection.Address
    Case TheWorksheet.Name = l_FuzzyLookup_AddIn_Undo_Sheet And Not swkstActiveFuzzyLookupSheet Is Nothing:
      With swkstActiveFuzzyLookupSheet.ListObjects(s_FuzzyLookupResultsTable)
        Ä.EnableEvents = False
          ' This is a Fuzzy Lookup bug work-around to show an in-cell error if the output doesn't update
          If .ListColumns.Count > 1 Then
            Dim strHeaderRowRange As String: strHeaderRowRange = .HeaderRowRange.Address
            Dim varHeaders() As Variant: varHeaders = ƒ.Transpose(ƒ.Transpose(.HeaderRowRange.Value2))
            With Range(.ListColumns(2).DataBodyRange, .ListColumns(.ListColumns.Count).DataBodyRange)
              Dim strDeletedRange As String: strDeletedRange = .Address
              .Delete
            End With
            Range(strDeletedRange).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
            Range(strDeletedRange).Value2 = s_InCell_Error_Message
            Range(strHeaderRowRange).Value2 = varHeaders
          End If
          ' This is the magic line that forces the output back into the table
          .HeaderRowRange.Cells(1).Select
        Ä.EnableEvents = True
      End With
    Case TheWorksheet.Name = swkstActiveFuzzyLookupSheet.Name:
      With swkstActiveFuzzyLookupSheet.ListObjects(s_FuzzyLookupResultsTable).Range
        If Target.Cells(Target.Cells.Count).Address = .Cells(.Cells.Count).Address Then
          ' <optional>
          ' Only restore the selection if set to do so and the selection is not the first header cell
          If RESTORE_SELECTION _
          And sstrOriginalSelection <> .Cells(1).Address _
          Then
            Ä.EnableEvents = False
              Range(sstrOriginalSelection).Select
            Ä.EnableEvents = True
            ' Unfortunately the above Select doesn't stick. The Add-in trys to change the selection another 1 or 2 times.
            ' The following hack is required so that the Workbook_SheetSelectionChange handler can revert these attempts.
            ' Note that if the original selection contains the first header cell, only 1 attempt is made. Otherwise it makes 2 attempts.
            RevertSelection _
              RevertTo:=Selection, _
              NumberOfTimes:=IIf(Intersect(Selection, .Cells(1)) Is Nothing, 2, 1)
          End If
          ' </optional>
          sstrOriginalSelection = vbNullString
          Set swkstActiveFuzzyLookupSheet = Nothing
        End If
      End With
    Case Else:
      Exit Sub
   'End Cases
  End Select

End Sub

' The following code is only needed if the RESTORE_SELECTION option is required.
' If the code is removed, the optional code in the Workbook_SheetChange handler above also needs to be removed.

Private Sub RevertSelectionIfRequired()
  RevertSelection
End Sub

Private Sub RevertSelection _
            ( _
              Optional ByRef RevertTo As Range, _
              Optional ByRef NumberOfTimes As Long _
            )

  Static srngRevertTo As Range
  Static slngRevertCount As Long

  Select Case True
    Case Not RevertTo Is Nothing:
      Set srngRevertTo = RevertTo
      slngRevertCount = NumberOfTimes
    Case Not srngRevertTo Is Nothing:
      With Application
        .EnableEvents = False
        srngRevertTo.Select
        .EnableEvents = True
      End With
      slngRevertCount = slngRevertCount - 1
      If slngRevertCount = 0 Then Set srngRevertTo = Nothing
    Case Else:
      Exit Sub
   'End Cases
  End Select

End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_SheetSelectionChange _
            ( _
                       ByVal TheWorksheet As Object, _
                       ByVal Target As Range _
            )

  RevertSelectionIfRequired

End Sub
```

Comment: I will add more information about the bugs, issues and caveats after I get some sleep ;-)

Answer (score 3):

The table is output starting at the active cell. So you have to choose where you want the table by clicking the upper left corner cell before you click "GO".

Comment: Is there a chance that you could edit your response to use direct object references over macro recorder?

Comment: I'm not clear on what you are asking.

Comment: Unfortunately, macro recorder spits nothing out when fuzzy matching is ran.

Comment: Maybe it can't be scripted because it's an external plugin.... I'll modify my answer